# How to send 2 Videos file path and name using InputStream in java

Tags: java, response, inputstream

The following code successfully sends one video file path and name, but I want to send 2 video path and name. How do I send 2nd video file path and name?

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(subscriberVideo.getVideoFilePath());
response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachement;filename=" + subscriberVideo.getFileName());
response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM.toString());
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
response.flushBuffer();
```